# Переименование проектов VS

Tags: visual-studio

Здравствуй,форум!!!

К примеру,программист **случайно**(ха-ха) создал проект с именем по умолчанию"ConsoleApplication1"

Как можно **безопасно переименовать проект** чтобы впоследствии,он открывался как надо,и не вылезали всякого рода ошибки.

Буду признателен,за развернутый ответ.

P.S В гугле по этому поводу **мало толковых ответов от специалистов**

Comment: Если проект только был создан, то проще пересоздать с нужным названием. А так лично в `Visual Studio 2019` если переименовать проект, то ошибок не будет, даже если переименовать решение.

Comment: "мало толковых ответов от специалистов" - что бы найти толковый ответ, надо уметь его понять.

Comment: Сколько раз пытался переименовать проект всегда вылезают какие-то ошибки по типу"Ваш проект не был найден/Удалить все ссылки о нем?"/И я не просил давать мне советы/я попросил дать нормальный ответ(можно ссылку на полезную информацию)

Comment: Кстати Павел Ериков спасибо за ответ!